# Fastest way to load Active Directory with dummy data?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In preparation for a test, we need to load a Windows Server VM with up to 400,000 users and 100,000 groups, and various mappings between them.

A powershell script has been written to achieve this, running on a Server 2012 R2 VM (4 cores, 8GB RAM). However, at the rate the script is running, it's looking like it could take more than a month to complete.

We've tried the script using both the net command and the Add-AD commands to see if there's any speed increase. There doesn't seem to be. The script uses several For loops to iterate through creating users, creating groups, and adding certain users numbers to group numbers.

Command examples were:

```
#net users $userName mypassword /add
#New-ADUser -Name $userName -SamAccountName $userName -DisplayName $userName -AccountPassword mypassword -Enabled $true

and

net group $groupName $userName /add
#Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $userName
```

Any suggestions on the **fastest** way to load an AD with a mass of new users/groups/mappings?

Thanks

Comment: For starters : benchmark (parts of) your script. See which part takes a long time to complete. The sample you provided is too minimal to give me any real indication of the cause (since you only listed some commands to create users)

Comment: my understanding is that the AD cmdlets are somewhat slower than the ADSI stuff ... have you tried replacing the longest running AD cmdlets with ADSI calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PowerShell cmdlets for AD are convenient, but they are *not* efficient.

Using ADSI directly will likely be faster because it gives you more control of what's going on. PowerShell has a shortcut notation of `[ADSI]"LDAP://thepath"` to create objects (they're technically `DirectoryEntry` object, but the examples here use the [`IADs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iads) methods).

There are instructions on creating users [here](https://www.petri.com/creating-active-directory-user-accounts-adsi-powershell), but I can summarize it:

```
[ADSI]$OU = "LDAP://OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local"
$new = $OU.Create("user","CN=Ginger Snaps")
$new.put("samaccountname","gsnaps")
$new.setinfo()

#Account is created disabled, so we need to enable and set a password
#(the password can't be set until it's created)
$new.put("userAccountControl",544)
$new.setpassword("P@ssw0rd")
$new.setinfo()
```

You use `$new.put()` for whatever other attributes you want to set. You can also create groups this way too, just use `"group"` instead of `"user"` in the `Create()` method.

This is still going to take a while. It's the network connections that will hurt you the most. So you have to:

1. Get as physically close to a DC as you can (run it *on* a DC if you can), and
2. Keep the number of network requests down

If you do run this on a DC, then (if the domain has more than one DC) make sure to target the DC that you're on. You can do that by injecting the DC name into the `LDAP://` strings, like this:

```
"LDAP://dc1.domain.com/OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local"
```

Number 2 is limited by the fact that you *have to* do 2 requests per new user (one to create, one to set password). But you can do other things to keep the number down, like create all the users first and store the `distinguishedName` of each new user, which you can calculate yourself (rather than asking AD for it) because it's the `CN=user` that you pass to `Create()` plus the OU. So for the example above, the DN of the new user is:

```
CN=Ginger Snaps,OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local
```

Once you have all those, you can create the groups and add all the members in one go. For example:

```
[ADSI]$OU = "LDAP://OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local"
$new = $OU.Create("group","CN=group1")
$new.put("samaccountname","group1")

$members = @("CN=Ginger Snaps,OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local", `
             "CN=Another User,OU=IT,OU=Departments,OU=Employees,DC=Globomantics,DC=Local")
$new.put("member", $members)
$new.setinfo()
```

Where `$members` is your array of the `distinguishedName` for each member.

This way you have one network request that creates the whole group with the members already set, rather than one network request for *each* member.